# Minecraft custom item texture - experiencing ghosting

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am attempting to create some HD textures for Minecraft (currently version 1.8.1). I succeeded in getting the image to load in the game, but it doesn't look right. It appears that the game is trying to create a thickness for the item (this example is an iron sword). I used the same resolution for a birch log block that turned out great, of course it's a square item so I can imagine that trying to create thickness of a hand-held item is more difficult.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to improve/remove this artifact for items?

Thanks.
[image: Iron Sword in Hand]

Edit: Here is the texture I used:

[image: Iron Sword Texture]

Comment: Mind posting the texture you used?

Comment: Updated the post to include the texture. It's a 256x256 PNG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minecraft uses the "edge" of an image when creating the 3D geometry. That means the pixel that defines the "edge" will be used for the full color.

In your case, the edge of the sword is of varying color and alpha values. This makes the sword picture "smooth" but it will mess up the color picking used for the 3D weapon. I would advise re-working the edge of the sword to fix the transparency. A hard edge is going to work best.

Comment: Thanks @Thebluefish, that was it. I still have some more work to do, still getting a bit of ghosting along the side, I'm sure there are some pixels I missed with my eraser, but it's definitely a path towards fixing the issue.

Comment: @TimS. What I would probably do is trace the edge with whatever color you want at top. Typically as I am very picky myself, I would select the entire transparent area, increase the selection size by 1-3px, and erase it. Then I would trace around the sword with a 1px line of whatever color that I would want the geometry to be.

Comment: Thebluefish that's exactly what I did actually (love the expand selection feature in photoshop), but I must have missed some of the pixels for the 1px line. I'll definitely get it, and it looks much nicer. Thanks for the assist!

Comment: Hope this helps. https://66ed39aec3765da25cfb6002b5fe7930221b5f18.googledrive.com/host/0Bwh-rUpGiETGWEtvc3E5Rm5zdE0/cleaned.png

Comment: that's an awesome texture. can you give us a download if it's done. looks awesome, very good job